# Tasm macros default value

Tags: assembly, macros, default, tasm

In turbo assembler i have a macro

```
subs macro x,y 
    mov ax,x
    sub ax,y
endm
```

how can I give to y a default value, equal to 1, so I can write

```
subs bx
```

and ax becomes equal to bx - 1?

Comment: Instead of a default value, it would be better to have a whole different expansion: `lea ax, [bx - 1]`.  This is better for any constant, not just a default 1, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subs MACRO x,y
    IFB <y>
        mov ax,x
        sub ax,1
    ELSE
        mov ax,x
        sub ax,y
    ENDIF
ENDM
```

You need a reference: http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/